# I am getting error while applying multiple joins in a select query

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a multi join query when I run it it me

> error :ORA-00904: "from$_subquery$_003"."PSR_PART_NBR": invalid identifier

But when I up down the inner joins it works fine Can someone give me the logical explanation what wrong with the sequence of joins.

```
select vsp.psr_sup_code supcom_sup_code,
       vsp.psr_part_nbr supcom_part_number,
       PSR_COM_CODE supcom_comm_code,
       '' supcom_comments,
       vpm.part_mod_user AS supcom_mod_user,
       vpm.part_mod_date AS supcom_mod_date,
       NULL supcom_map_id,
       vsp.psr_reg_code supcom_reg_code,
       vsp.psr_prdline_code supcom_prdline_code,
       1 supcom_prgs_flag, 
       NVL (vcs.segment_code, '*') sub_commodity_code 
FROM vin_psr_sup_prt_plnt_dtl vsp
   INNER JOIN vin_sup_supplier_mst vsm ON (vsp.psr_sup_code = vsm.supplier_code  AND vsm.supplier_code_type = 'mstr')
   INNER JOIN vin_core_part_mst vpm  ON (vsp.psr_part_nbr = vpm.part_number)
   LEFT OUTER JOIN v_commodity_segment_structure vcs ON (vpm.commodity_mapping_id = vcs.comdmap_id);
```

Comment: A missing ) after `vpm.part_number`

Comment: Can we see the tablets?

Comment: I cant give the tables they are huge and the bracket is not issue

Comment: `vin_psr_sup_prt_plnt_dtl` table can have column name `PSR_PART_NBR`

Comment: Only thing I don't get is that what happens when I up down the inner joins and It works

Comment: yes vin_psr_sup_prt_plnt_dtl have PSR_PART_NBR

Answer (score 0):

vsp.psr_sup_code as supcom_sup_code,
       vsp.psr_part_nbr as supcom_part_number,
       PSR_COM_CODE as supcom_comm_code,

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem caused by bug in version 11.2.0.4,it appears randomly in queries using subqueries or ansi join.

In my case I found the root cause: It was caused when I did a expdp from 11.2.0.4 and the schema has MATERIALIZED VIEWS. Then I did an impdp in other DataBase (10g, 11g and even 12c). Some kind of diccionary problem causes the bug.

I solved doing this:

1. EXPDP excluding MATERIALIZED_VIEWS
2. IMPDP. There were some errors related to MATERIALIZED_VIEW objects, wich were ignored.
3. Create manually all the MATERIALIZED_VIEW objects.
4. Recompile all objects in database, using “$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql”

This is an extract of the bug documentation:

> **Bug 17551261  ORA-904 "from$_subquery$_003". with query 
>   rewrite**
>
> This note gives a brief overview of bug 17551261.
>   The content was last updated on: 21-FEB-2014
>
> **Affects:**
>
> Product (Component)   Oracle Server (Rdbms)
>
> Range of versions believed to be affected Versions BELOW 12.1
>
> Versions confirmed as being affected  **11.2.0.4**
>
> Platforms affected    Generic (all / most platforms affected)
>
> It is believed to be a regression in default behaviour thus:
>   Regression introduced in 11.2.0.4
>
> **Fixed:** The fix for 17551261 is first
>   included in   •   12.1.0.1 (Base Release)
>
> **Description** This
>   problem is introduced in 11.2.0.4 by the fix for bug 14049796 .
>
> If an ORA-904 similar to the following is raised:
>   *ORA-00904: "from$_subquery$_003"."SUBSCRIBER_SID": invalid identifier* 
>   from a SQL statement using ANSI joins,  then it may be a case of this
>   bug if all of the following are true:
>
> 1) Summary rewrite is used
>
> 2) fix to bug:14049796 present (this fix is included in 11.2.0.4)
>
> 3) The errorstack includes kkogvcd() and kkqsgen()
>
> **Workaround**  Disable query rewrite